# Can't use RubyPress gem gives getaddrinfo: No such host is known. (SocketError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubypress

I am trying to use a gem called [RubyPress](https://github.com/zachfeldman/rubypress) which allows to use Wordpress' xml-rpc api from ruby. But it always gives me this error:

```
getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (SocketError)
```

Here's my code:

```
require 'rubypress'
wp = Rubypress::Client.new(:host => "localhost/wordpress", 
                           :username => "admin", 
                           :password => "admin")
p wp.getOptions
```

I am able to connect fine using another gem called [wp_rpc](https://github.com/alexferreira/wp_rpc) but rubypress doesn't seem to work. Rubypress seems to be maintained so i want to use it, it also seems to have more features.

Also, even when i try connecting to a real site, it gives a 403 error which is very strange.

I am running the server using XAMPP on Windows 7. How can I get it to work?

UPDATE:
Here's the code i used for posting, now it doesn't seem to post. Not sure where i went wrong.

```
wp.newPost( :blog_id => 0, # 0 unless using WP Multi-Site, then use the blog id
            :content => {
                         :post_status  => "publish",
                         :post_date    => Time.now,
                         :post_content => "This is the body",
                         :post_title   => "RubyPress is the best!",
                         :post_name    => "/rubypress-is-the-best",
                         :post_author  => 1, # 1 if there is only the admin user, otherwise the user's id
                         :terms_names  => {
                            :category   => ['Category One','Category Two','Category Three'],
                            :post_tag => ['Tag One','Tag Two', 'Tag Three']
                                          }
                         }
            )
```

Note: This is from the rubypress github page. Those categories and tags are not present on the blog, is that the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`host` must be a host name (e.g. `"localhost"` in this particular case, or, say, `"google.com"`):

```
require 'rubypress'
wp = Rubypress::Client.new(host: "localhost",
                           username: "admin",
                           password: "admin",
                           path: "/wordpress/xmlrpc.php")
```

Probably, you might need to tune the `path` parameter up to point exactly to where WP’s RPC endpoint is to be found.

Comment: sorry to bother once again, it fetches the data properly but now i can't seem to post to the blog. I just updated the code in question.